# I am using Nginx to host my React application that makes calls to a Django application. Getting "Too many redirects" error when I visit the site

Tags: python, reactjs, nginx, gunicorn

My React application is set up internally to make calls to my application built using Django Rest Framework. I am using both Gunicorn and Nginx, here is my Nginx config file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

    # Root directory of React build
    root /home/ubuntu/Project-Frontend/build;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }

    # Proxy requests to Django backend
    location /userapi/ {
        proxy_pass https://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

The Nginx server worked until I attempted to add SSL using Certbot, after which I am just completely unable to access the site. I have tried checking both applications for issues and have found nothing. I have also been looking through similar posts to try and find a solution and so far nothing has worked, I would be extremely grateful for any help.

Comment: I would try `curl -v https://www.example.com` and see what the site is redirecting you to - that's the `Location` header. Are you using client-side routing, e.g. `react-router`?